# Make div visible at a location on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am looking for a code that makes a `div` visible on a certain location on the webpage. when you scroll trough the website you get at certain headings when you are at a specific heading the div needs to get visible in the navbar.

The div #greybar is the div that needs to get visible only on a certain location while scrolling, the whole navbar is fixed

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logotekst.png">
        </div>

        <div id="menubutton"><a onclick="playclip();" href="#homejump">Home</div>
        <div id="menubutton"><a onclick="playclip();" href="#aboutjump">About</div>
        <div id="menubutton"><a onclick="playclip();" href="#infojump">Info</div>
        <div id="menubutton"><a onclick="playclip();" >test</div>

    </div>
    <div id="greybar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#greybar {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color: #A4A4A4;
}
```

Comment: what has this got to do with java? what css have you tried? position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 400px;

Comment: And what has this got to do with PHP? Do you mean javascript ;) ?

Comment: If you want help show at least the html for the DIV you are talking about. There are some pretty good people here, **but they are not clairvoyant**

Comment: i just put java in the tag because it tough that was maybe a solution, i have not tried anything like the position the div is located in the navbar. while you scroll the div needs to be visible on a certain part

Comment: This part is unclear " to make it visible on the navbar when you are at a certain heading" ...can you please make yourself a bit clear

Comment: I see that this is your first question on StackExchange. Therefore I advise you to read the following page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I edited already some tags in your question and changed some grammar. Now we need a piece of code from your side.

Comment: added some of the code from the part i am talking about also edited the question and explained it better

Answer (score -1):

If you are using javascript and jQuery, you can have a look at jQuery functions 
[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/). At the end of all pages, there are good examples.

EDIT: You should rather use `class="menubutton"` and not `id="menubutton"`.

After that, you can use script like

```
    <script>
    $( "div.menubutton" ).hover(
      function() {
        $( "#greybar" ).text( $( this ).text());
        $( "#greybar" ).show();
      }, function() {
        $( "#greybar" ).hide();
        $( "#greybar" ).text("");
      }
    );
    </script>
```

EDIT 2:
add to greybar class `position: fixed;`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question (the question is too vague to answer in its current form)

Comment: I understand the question exactly as it was extended. Now I have improved the answer to reflect HTML structure.

Comment: i will look a bit into this script and look if i can do something with it, thanks